# Присваивается одинаковое значение в цикле при использовании указателя &

Tags: golang, graphql, google-protobuf

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
)



type statusListSource struct {
  Id               uint64
  Status           *string
  StatusId     uint64
  StatusNext       *string
  StatusNextId   uint64      
}

type statusList struct {
  Id               uint64
  Status           string
  StatusId     uint64
  StatusNext       string
  StatusNextId   uint64      
}

func main() {
  // исходные данные
  var listSource []statusListSource
  
  listSource = statusData()

  // для хранения результатов
  var states []*statusList

  for _, a := range listSource {

    state := &statusList{
      Id:        a.Id,
      Status:         &a.Status,
      StatusId:    a.StatusId,
      StatusNext:     &a.StatusNext,
      StatusNextId:  a.StatusNextId,
    }

    states = append(states, state)
  }
  
    
  fmt.Println(states)
}
```

Схема     schema.graphql для protobuf

```
type statusList {
  id: Int!
    status: String
    status_id: Int!
    status_next: String
    status_next_id: Int!
}
```

Соответственно поля status и status_next необязательны , по этому protobuf их генерирует с типом со указателем *

Проблема в том что после цикла status и status_next одинаковые для всех элементом цикла, хотя они разные должны быть. Как это исправить?

Comment: Про это даже в [F.A.Q.](https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines) написано.  Там про горутины, но механизм тот же самый.  Переменные цикла не меняют адрес между итерациями.

Comment: Благодарю. я ещё новичок в golang